# TChromiumFMX - Create at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I'm currently trying to create a basic web browser in Firemonkey with TChromiumFMX. I originally posted to the group for the project but received no response in several weeks.

There appears to be an issue while attempting to create a TChromiumFMX at runtime. I initially attempted to create it from within my application. As that threw up Access Violation errors, i then tried the DLL route with exported procedures.

The error is as such;
Exception Class: EAccessViolation
Exception Message: Access violation at address  in module . Read of address 00000000.

The first address is seemingly random dependant on what i change within my code (slight tweaks to attempt to fix it, all to no avail), while the second address is always 00000000. For example; Access Violation at address 0117B40A in 'ChromDLL.dll'. Read of address 00000000.

Code is as follows;

```
[Global Variables]
Chrom : TChromiumFMX;

[...]

Procedure Chrom_Create(AlignTo : TAlignLayout; ParentIn :
TFmxObject; DefaultURLIn : String); export;
begin
  Chrom := TChromiumFMX.Create(nil);
  Chrom.Parent := ParentIn;
  Chrom.Align := AlignTo;
  Chrom.Options.CaretBrowsingEnabled := True;
  Chrom.Options.ThreadedCompositingEnabled := True;
  Chrom.Options.EncodingDetectorEnabled := True;
  Chrom.Options.FullscreenEnabled := True;
  Chrom.Options.FileAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed := True;
  Chrom.DefaultUrl := DefaultUrlIn;
end;
```

That's from the DLL version, but the code i wrote within the application version was very similar and also fails with a similar Access Violation.

This issue only occurs with the FMX/Firemonkey component and does NOT occur with the VCL version using similar code (where TChromiumFMX is replaced with TChromium).

I'm curious if anyone has discovered a fix for this yet? I've searched and searched for weeks now, and have yet to find a solution, and the few people even talking about similar issues were on the issues page of Google Code. I did try forcefully assigning it's owner and parent to an object with the "in-application" version of the code but again, no such luck. The access violation occurs when i tell it to navigate to a URL.

I did notice that i had to call "Application.OnIdle" to "doOnIdleEvent" and "FLoading" to "False" when the form is created in order for the initial browser window that's been created at design time to function, but i've had no luck with doing the same when i create one at runtime.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:** Fixed a typo that shouldn't have carried across

Comment: This can't be your actual code (you declare `Chrom`, you create `Chron`, but access `Chrom` in all but two lines (note the last character in each name)). An AV with an address of all zeros means it's a null pointer being accessed; did you use the debugger to identify where it's happening?

Comment: :) You fixed the typo in the variable names, but didn't do anything to address the other half of my comment. Which line is causing the AV to occur? The debugger should help you figure that out.

Comment: Good catch there Ken. It was actually a typo when i copied the code over to SO, and as such that typo doesn't exist in the code.
The CPU window indicates it's a `mov ecx,[eax]`, and that it's located inside the unit that `chrom` is being created in. However, i believe i've tracked it down to an event i was using to load the url (sender hadn't been called correctly). I'll tweak with it and report back.